# How to print out a row from a csv file exactly how it is written?

Tags: python, function, csv

I have to create a function which looks for the ID column of a file (as it could be indexed anywhere in the header), once it is found the ID column will check if a given ID is equal to any IDs in the column. If yes, it returns the row of data associated with that given ID. **Imports of any kind cannot be used.** I've got the first part right but the last test case is throwing me off because the columns are not the same, therefore I am not getting the answer in the correct order.

(I have previous functions written that open and read files etc)
This is my current code:

```
def ecu_data(arbitration_id, data):
    """ Returns a list of the timestamp and data of an arbitration_ID. """
    rows = []
    arb_index = data[0].index("Arbitration_ID")
    for row in data[0:]:
        if row[arb_index] == arbitration_id:
            rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

and the three test cases are:

```
data = get_data("file1.csv")
edata = ecu_data('153', data)
print(edata[0])
```

```
data = get_data("file1.csv")
edata = ecu_data('153', data)
print(edata[22])
```

```
data = get_data("file3.csv")
edata = ecu_data('368', data)
print(edata[1])
```

The first two cases expect & receive the outputs: `['1597759710.1258929', '153', '8', '20 A1 10 FF 00 FF 50 1F', 'Normal', 'Normal']` and `['1597759710.345933', '153', '8', '20 A1 10 FF 00 FF C0 8F', 'Normal', 'Normal']`
whereas the third case expects the output: `['1597759356.234800', '8', '368', '00 00 00 00 00 FA 0A 40', 'Normal', 'Normal']` and receives: `['1597759356.234800', '368', '8', '00 00 00 00 00 FA 0A 40', 'Normal', 'Normal']`

How do I fix my code so that the rows print exactly how they are in their files?

Comment: You're not performing any transformations on the data in this function, so it must have been messed up before it got here.  You didn't share that code.

Comment: @MarkRansom I can't see the data from the third file but the expected output tells me the ID column is the 2nd index, not the 3rd. However, I can't just make that assumption for other possible test cases. And the columns aren't supposed to be static. That's why I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes a csv filename and an ID to search for.  It will open the file, and then use `DictReader` to read each row with the header row to a dictionary. Then it will return the `values()` of any rows where the `Arbitration_ID` matches `search_id` (or you could return the dict too by dropping `.values()`)

```
import csv
def find_rows_by_id(file, search_id):
    with open(file) as f:
        return [row.values() for row in csv.DictReader(f) if row['Arbitration_ID'] == search_id]

print(find_rows_by_id('file1.csv','153'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the challenge is to not use any imports of any kind, otherwise I would've gone with this approach!!

Comment: you should state that in your question

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet that has a function that will probably help you in fixing your problem.

**Explanation:**

1. This function reads the specified file using a 'with' statement.
2. Now we will read the first line and split it using the ','(comma) separator as we have a CSV file. The *strip()* function is used to remove the presence of any empty characters or spaces in the elements generated by the *split(',')* function.
3. As mentioned that the ID column can be indexed anywhere in the header, we will store its index value in a variable *id_index* and use that for our reference.
4. And if the **ID** column is not found, we will return **None** as our output.
5. We will now loop through the file and use the similar function *.strip()* and *.split(',')* to store the instance of the particular row in each iteration.
6. Now comes the final part; we will use conditional statements and check for the instance of the row for whom the ID is satisfied and finally return the entire row.

**Code:**

```
def find_row_by_id(filename, id_to_find):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
        id_index = None
        for i, col_name in enumerate(header):
            if col_name == 'ID':
                id_index = i
                break
        if id_index is None:
            return None

        for line in f:
            row = line.strip().split(',')
            if row[id_index] == id_to_find:
                return row

    return None
```